# Android intent extra data is lost

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to get some data passed along inside my app using intents' extras.

I attach data to the intent like so:

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityFrom.this, ActivityTo.class);
i.putExtra(CONST_KEY, true);
startActivity(i);
```

With

```
public static final String CONST_KEY = "MyBooleanValue";
```

I'm attempting to retrieve the data in the started ActivityTo's onCreate method like so:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
    if ( extra != null ) {
        boolean b = extra.getBoolean(ActivityFrom.CONST_KEY);
    }
}
```

However, I never run into the if-block, because the `Bundle` is always `null`.

Why are my extras lost? What do I need to change to retrieve the extras I put to the intent?

*Edit*

- Corrected the typo in code
- Added the complete `onCreate` method declaration
- Here is the `ActivityTo`'s declaration in the manifest:

  ```
  <activity
      android:name=".ActivityTo"
      android:launchMode="singleTask"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait">
  </activity>
  ```

Comment: can you please post ActivityTo's onCreate also the activity declaration in the manifest file ?

Comment: "getExtras" and not getExtra!!

Comment: Remove `singleTask` launch mode. You shouldn't be doing that anyway.

Comment: @DavidWasser Why not?

Comment: In general, the special launch modes "singleTask" and "singleInstance" should only be used in very specific cases, like when you are creating a "launcher" or HOME-screen replacement. They have a ton of side-effects that are not obvious at firt glance, and 99% of the time they are used when they shouldn't be, and create more problems than they solve. The standard default behaviour should work for most applications.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is the `android:launchMode="singleTask"`attribute of the receiving task. With this being set, all intents that target the `ActivityTo` activity are received by the same object. In case the activity was already created, the intent is sent through the activity's `onNewIntent(Intent)` method. Override it like this:

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
}
```

This way, you can get the new intent with the `getIntent()`.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your object properties in 
`writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags)` match reading from parcel in `YourObject(in)`

for example

```
public class User implements Parcelabel { 
private String name;
private String addrss;
private String city;

// read from parcel
protected User(Parcel in) {
name = parcel.readString();
address = parcel.readString();
city = parcel.readString();
}

// write to parcel
writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags){
parcel.writeString(name);
parcel.writeString(address);
parcel.writeString(city);
}
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I think you should try

```
if(getIntent().getBooleanExtra(ActivityFrom.CONST_KEY,false)!=null){
     Boolean b=getIntent().getBooleanExtra(ActivityFrom.CONST_KEY,false);
}
```

Comment: The `getBooleanExtra` method requires two parameters: the key and the default value in case no value was found under that specified key. This code snippet fails to compile.

Comment: It still fails to compile, because the `getBooleanExtra()` method returns a primitive `boolean`, not a `Boolean` object. Hence, it cannot be compared to `null`.

Comment: This answer is useless. And wrong. If you want to know if an extra exists in an `Intent`, you use `hasExtra(key)`.